# how can i get all Latitude and Longitude from 1km radius through my current Latitude and Longitude

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to fetch all the latitude and longitude within the radius of 1km through my current lat and lon.

Suppose i have the current `lat:28.541743483605376 and lon:77.2174072265625 and i have define radius: 1` km then i want to fetch all lat and lon from that 1 km radius.

How can i do this?

Comment: What do you mean by *"all latitudes and longitudes within 1km"*? If you do that with a 1m resolution you will end up with over 3 million points...

Comment: I am creating live tracking application.
Now i want give alert if that person is comes in that 1km radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you are doing now....

Get the point and get the person's location, then use the Haversine Formula to see if the distance between the two points is less than 1km.

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), or find your favourite language in this list for the corresponding implementation... [list of implementations](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).